# Where to put providers in NextJs 13?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm using the date library by [Mui](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/getting-started/) and it requires a provider to be wrapped around all components:

```
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs'

function App({ children }) {
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      {children}
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

But there's no corresponding App function in NextJs 13 which only offers pages in the `/app` directory.

Comment: use the `RootLayout` file

Answer (score 1):

In Next.js 13, the App function is replaced by the root layout in the app directory. You can wrap your provider around all components in the app/layout.tsx file:

```
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs'

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <html lang="en">
        <body>{children}</body>
      </html>
    </LocalizationProvider>
  )
}
```

This will apply the LocalizationProvider to all routes inside app. The children prop will be populated with nested layouts or pages

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow, CyberJ.

It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies since at least *eight* of of your answers yesterday appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The React Query docs explain how to handle this exact issue https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/framework/react/guides/advanced-ssr#initial-setup

Effectively, create a `<Providers/>` client component which accepts & renders `children` props. Wrap your Mui provider around the `{children}` in that component.

```
// In Next.js, this file would be called: app/providers.jsx
'use client'

export default function Providers({ children }) {

  return (
    <SomeProvider>{children}</SomeProvider>
  )
}
```

Then import `<Providers/>` into `layout.tsx` as a child of `<body>`

```
// In Next.js, this file would be called: app/layout.jsx
import Providers from './providers'

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head />
      <body>
        <Providers>{children}</Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```